# Android Fragment Manipulation

Tags: android, fragment

I've a simple application Structure. I've a navigation drawer which has three options so three fragments. One of these fragment contains a list of 50 items ( 50 cars) . Each one if these cars takes the user a new fragment where he can see details about the cars.
The goal was that when the user is browsing one of those cars, he would have a bottom page that pops up and lets him jump between cars, rather having to go back to the list every time he wants to change Items. I've implemented this bottom page but I've a problem.

whenever I'm inside a car, and i go to another car via this bottom page, when i hit back , I'm correctly going to the list of 50 cars and not the first car i clicked on, However I'm having some weird artifacts mainly the option menus in the top right are the ones that belong to the cars fragment and not the list-of-cars fragment.

When I'm inside the list of 50 cars and I want to open a new car:

```
            Fr_Dets frDets = new Fr_Dets();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout_for_fragments, frDets, "fragmentcardetails");
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
```

When I'm inside a car fragment and I click on another car:

```
        Fr_Dets frDets = new Fr_Dets();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout_for_fragments, frDets, "fragmentcardetails");
        transaction.commit();
        dismiss();
```

Comment: Are you calling `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` inside your fragments' `onCreate()` method?

Comment: @y.allam yes I am am calling it in the oncreate in every fragment, including the list of cars and the cars fragment

Comment: Ideally in the future cut down the excess of information, is the only bug here that your options menu is not changing when you select the back button? Also is there a specific reason you aren't having your navigation drawer switch between activities instead of fragments?

Comment: @Ryan post the fragments code, it will help understand the problem more